# Can i use encrypt/decrypt SQLite in MvvmCross

Tags: sqlite, encryption, xamarin, mvvmcross, sqlcipher

Give me the way, how i can encrypt/decrypt SQLite with MvvmCross, please.

I'm writing the app on Xamarin for two platforms, iOS and Android. And i'm using MvvmCross in the project.

I'm so confused.

The better way is [**SQLitePCL.raw**](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw) with [**sqlcipher**](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher), i guess. But i don't know how exactly combine sqlcipher with SQLitePCL.raw. I can use some SQLitePCL.plugins.* for adding "sqlcipher provider" to each platform, but how it use on C# level? How i can set PRAGMA key into my C# code, for example?

Comment: There are Components for SQLite encryption: https://components.xamarin.com/view/sqlcipher-for-xamarin-ios and https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlcipher-for-xamarin-android

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe Yeah, i saw. Do you know some free packages / ways?

Comment: I've once created a binding for the android community edition for a stackoverflow answer: https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-sqlcipher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the answer was to use that scheme.

For Core project I used next packages:

```
SQLitePCLRaw.core
SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_sqlcipher
```

For iOS project:

```
SQLitePCLRaw.core
SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_sqlcipher
SQLitePCLRaw.lib.sqlcipher.ios_unified.static
SQLitePCLRaw.provider.internal.ios_unified
```

And for Android project:

```
SQLitePCLRaw.core
SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_sqlcipher
SQLitePCLRaw.lib.sqlcipher.android
SQLitePCLRaw.provider.sqlcipher.android
```

Before you will try to use any method from SQLitePCLRaw packages you need setup provider. For that you just have to input one line of code:

```cs
SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();
```

More information about SQLitePCLRaw packages on [github](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/wiki/SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init)